# vim & vscode: remapping redo to "U"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I am trying to remap the redo command to "U" do that "u" will undo and "U" will redo. I am using vim with vscode and I am trying to change the bindings with this but it is not working.

```json
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["U"],
            "after": [],
            "commands": [
                {
                    "command": "redo",
                    "args": []
                }
            ]
         },
      ],
```

Answer (score 3):

```json
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
        ...
        {
            "before": ["U"],
            "after": ["C-r"]
         },
      ],
```